# django getlist() function

Tags: django, django-views, django-templates

I have a tags generator for my blog site and every time I enter tags it generates a hidden html input, and it appends whenever I insert a tag like this example below.

```
<input type="hiiden" name="tags" value="<value of inserted tags>">
<input type="hiiden" name="tags" value="<value of inserted tags>">
<input type="hiiden" name="tags" value="<value of inserted tags>">
```

In my Django view I get all the tags from the form through **request.POST.getlist("tags")** and save it on database so the inserted tags is like this on database **['value1','value2','value3']** When I fetch the tags in the Django template through for loop to extract the strings from the arrayfield the output shows like this:

```
[ ' v a l u e 1 ' , ' v a l u e 2 ' , ' v a l u e 3 ' ] // one by one character output
```

the code works fine but the problem is it outputs character by character in the array including the brackets and the apostrophe and the commas. What i want to achieve is only the strings which are present in the array field

anyone knows what can be the solution for this? any suggestion and help is appreciated.

Comment: why you want to achieve is only the strings which are present in the array field? 
You want show value it in django template?

Comment: @NgocPham yes I want to show it on template but it output every character including the array brackets, apostrophe and commas

Comment: can you add your code for generate it, include how you use request.POST.getlist("tags") ?